# how to use blog variable on javascript

Tags: javascript, blogs, blogspot

I'm using blogger.com. I need to use data:blog.url variable on the javascript. But i don't know how to assign to any javascript variable.

How to get blogspot variables on the javascript?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if this doesn't works:

```
<script>
  var blogURL = '<data:blog.url/>';
</script>
```

then try this:

```
<div id="blogurl" style="display:none;"><data:blog.url/></div>
<script>
  var blogURL = document.getElementById('blogurl').innerHTML;
</script>
```

But if you want to get the page URL in javascript you can use `window.location`

disclaimer: i've never used blogger

Comment: Thank you. That is helpful. If you know about blogger language book or syntax language (b:if ...), tell me please

Comment: Well, what i've done is just download a template and look into the xml file. for books: http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_ss?url=search-alias%3Dstripbooks&field-keywords=blogger and also: http://bloggerfordummies.blogspot.com/2006/04/blogger-template-tutorial.html